# Can I call page_load event of usercontrol before page_load event of aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, qtreeview

The question is straight forward.Can I call page_load of usercontrol before page_load of aspx page?

***EDIT***

*Its not possible to call the child's page_load event before parent's page_load.*

I have this aspx class called just4test for testing puropse.
Its aspx code is:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <uc1:lcont ID="lcont1" runat="server" />
  <div>

  </div>
  </form>
```

As you can see it is using a usercontrol file.

And its code behind is :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lcont1.my_tv_SelectedNodeChanged(sender, e);
    }
 }
```

Now the usercontrol is:

```
public partial class lcont : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
sql_con sq = new sql_con();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        bind_data();
    }
}

public void mytry()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("helo");
    }
public void bind_data()
{
    main_cat mcobj = new main_cat();
    List<main_cat> mclist = new List<main_cat>();
    mclist = mcobj.get_mcatlist();

    populatetree(mclist);
}

public void populatetree(List<main_cat> mytnode)
{
    TreeNode parentnode = null;
    foreach (main_cat mc in mytnode)
    {
        parentnode = new TreeNode(mc.Cname, mc.Cid.ToString());
        foreach (sub_cat sc in mc.scl)
        {
            TreeNode cnode = new TreeNode(sc.PRODUCT, sc.SID.ToString());
            parentnode.ChildNodes.Add(cnode);
        }
        parentnode.Collapse();
        my_tv.Nodes.Add(parentnode);
    }
}

public void my_tv_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeView tv = sender as TreeView;
    //TreeView tv = new TreeView();
    var selectedN = tv.SelectedNode;

    if (selectedN.Parent != null)
    {
        var id = tv.SelectedNode.Value;
        var name = tv.SelectedNode.Text;
        //Session["mySvar"] = id;

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "nething", "show("+id+")", true);
    }
    else
    {
        //Response.Redirect("test.aspx");
    }


}
```

}

I need to call the function my_tv_SelectedNodeChanged(sender, e); of usercontrol before the page_load of just4test page and i have done so.But when i run the program it says

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What should i do?

Comment: You mean to say Child came before Parent.

Comment: i don't think its possible

Comment: You can't make the child without the parent... that goes far beyond programming. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I was just confused..now i am sure thats not possible.I have a scenario where i need to call a function of usercontrol before page_load of aspx file.

Comment: You should update your question with your real question... for instance it might be acceptable to just reference the page from the user control at the end of loading it (although this creates a dependency)

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load no, but OnInit occures before. Depends on your actual problem, you can move your logic there.

Or call a public method of the User control before you do anything else in the Parent Page Page_Load event

See [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I have updated the question.And as you can see i have called public method of usercontrol before any other thing and this is what i need but its not working.HELp!!!

Comment: Or can i call a function of the same aspx after page_load?

Comment: It's hard to guess what are you trying to do...
From your code we can see that you bind your data in the user control when page is loaded for the first time (!Page.IsPostBack) and then what ever you do on your page when it's get posted back your main page fires the selection change event of the treelist, but that doesn't do anything, as nothing really changed (my guess)