# Is it possible to call a function after Page_Load event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this page say test.aspx.Its codebehind is like the code below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public void display()
{
   // some block statements
}
```

Since the function `display()` is outside the `Page_Load` it is never called. So how do 
I make this call to this function after `Page_Load`.

NOTE: I need this function outside the `Page_Load`.

Comment: maybe call loadcomplete then read about the life cycle here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Related and Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24751494/1324033

Comment: @Sayse and it is not answered.

Comment: Solution can be found here.. Almost similar post http://stackoverflow.com/q/11235062/3761928

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Page.LoadComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    display();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //call your function
    display(); 
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //call your function even later in the page life cycle
    display(); 
}

public void display()
{
  // some block statements
}
```

Here is the documentation that discusses the various Page Life Cycle methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.90).aspx

After Page_Load you have:

- PreRender
- Render
- Unload

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load that function on the time of load only then do like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isPostBack)
    {
        display();
    }

}

public void display()
{
   // some block statements
}
```

as this will load only once. But if u want to load it on each post back then do like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isPostBack)
    {}
    dispplay();
}

public void display()
{
   // some block statements
}
```

There's a default event called `Page_LoadComplete` which will execute when page is loaded fully
But,If you write your code in a `Page_Load` Event that code will execute and your controls will be accessible there
So best to call like in a page_load for once with first postback ;)

But, still if you want to go after page load then go for the `Page_LoadComplete`

```
  protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        display();
    }


 public void display()
    {
       // some block statements
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Both of your examples would still call the function in the `Page_Load` event. He needs to call it *after*. From the OP: `NOTE: I need this function outside the Page_Load.`

Comment: oh.. let me change then... @DGibbs and thanx for pointing it out